# What shell is the closest to C/C++ syntax?

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation

I am new to the Linux world, and I have been using Windows and writing Visual C++ for the past year or so. I find that bash seems to be the most popular shell in the Linux world. Is there a Linux CLI shell that would be the closest to bash capabilities but with C/C++ types syntax?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want it, though. Not even Windows' shells (cmd.exe, powershell) have a C-like syntax.

Comment: @muru Because I am very familiar with C syntax and I don't need to deal with a steep learning curve at this point in time. Maybe later down the road I will look into the pros any cons of the other shells available and use whichever fits my needs at the time.

Comment: That's a bad way to go about this. You're assuming a steep learning curve - yet you don't give any weight to how differences between actual C syntax and a shell's approximation of it could screw you over. Take the plunge, unless you're doing complex scripting, bash is pretty easy. Here's the [TLDP Bash beginner's guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/) - it's old, but good for a starting point.

Comment: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/

Comment: @muru Thanks for your input, but I promise you that I have given bash a go before looking elsewhere. Don't assume that just because I ask a question means that I haven't done any research at all.

Comment: Well, then, all I can say is that the C shell has the worst reputation among shells I have heard of. If you found bash less than pleasant, don't believe (t)csh will be better just because they have C-like syntax.

Comment: @muru So what shell would you recommend for me. I am competent in Powershell in Windows, you know my background in C, and I am trying to automate calling python pip to update packages ota, or using another method to push my python ota to my 28 wifi linked devices on my local network. Or should I start a new question for that?

Comment: @RedDogAlpha I would still suggest bash. It is pretty competent for scripting. What does your WiFi-linked devices have? If they're also using Ubuntu, and have SSH, you can do: `for h in host1 host2 …; do ssh $h "pip do something"; done`. If the hostnames or IP addresses have a pattern, we could even generate them using bash.

Comment: @Gokul_uf I will mark and answer after I receive a bit more input from other people. You listed one shell, well technically two shells, but I want to know if there are any other options out there as well. If I leave it unanswered a few more hours, there may be someone else who has another option to add. This is not only for my benefit, but for all of those who will come after me with the same question. So far yours is the best answer, although the other answer is interesting. Plus I want to see how the community votes on the answers to help meet evaluate the best one.

Comment: @RedDogAlpha well, [there aren't many shells.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_command_shells#General_characteristics) When it comes to shells you can install and run in a modern Linux system, tcsh is pretty much it for you. Nearly all the other shells have a Bourne-shell-like syntax (Bash is Bourne Again SHell, Bourne Shell's successor), except `fish` and [`rc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rc), `fish` isn't C-like at all, and `rc` is only C-like in using braces.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's CSH which fits the bill.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell)

> The C shell (csh or the improved version, tcsh, on most machines) is a
>   Unix shell that was created by Bill Joy while he was a graduate
>   student at University of California, Berkeley in the late 1970s. It
>   has been distributed widely, beginning with the 2BSD release of the
>   BSD Unix system that Joy began distributing in 1978.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh) Other early
>   contributors to the ideas or the code were Michael Ubell, Eric Allman,
>   Mike O'Brien and Jim Kulp.

[Man page](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/csh.1.asp)

Or you could try TCSH (Thanks! @muru)

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh)

> tcsh (/ˌtiːˈsiːʃɛl/ "tee-cee-shell", /ˈtiːʃɛl/ "tee-shell", or as an
>   acronym "tee cee ess aitch") is a Unix shell based on and compatible
>   with the C shell (csh). It is essentially the C shell with
>   programmable command-line completion, command-line editing, and a few
>   other features. Unlike the other common shells, functions cannot be
>   defined in a tcsh script and the user must use aliases instead (as in
>   csh).

Note that these shells are not as widely used as bash and hence some makefiles and shell scripts may behave unpredictably.

[Man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh)

Comment: [Tcsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcsh) for the modern world.

Comment: It is always preferred to add information locally rather than just links, as you are new I did it for you, see how much more useful that is.

Comment: @markkirby thanks, I'll remember this when I write answers in the future

Comment: It should be noted that csh is not only less used, but widely regarded as less suitable for scripting in general, so if a bashism or POSIX-ism doesn't work in tcsh, it is unlikely the author has provided a csh equivalent.

Answer (score 10):

Bash supports some C-style syntax. For example:

- Function declarations / definitions are sintactically similar to function declarations / definitions in C, except you dont't define neither parameters (which are fetched using the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, ...) nor return types (Bash doesn't use types at all):

  ```bsh
  foo() {
      # ...
  }
  ```

  Or again similarily to C using an inline declaration / definition:

  ```bsh
  foo() { #...; }
  ```

  To be noted that when using an inline declaration / definition the first and last statement must be space-separated from `{` and `}` respectively and that (again similarily to C) every statement must be semicolon-separated from the others and that the final statement must end with a semi-colon:

  ```bsh
  foo() { command1; command2; command3; }
  ```

  For completeness, an alternative way of declaring / defining function is using the keyword `function`, which doesn't need the `()` after the function's name:

  ```bsh
  function foo {
      #...
  }
  ```
- You can evaluate C-style expression by enclosing them in double parenthesis `(())`: quite a number of C-style operators are supported, (including assignment), e.g.: `=`, `>`, `>=`, `==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `&&`, `||`, `!`, among others:

  ```bsh
  $ i=0
  $ j=1
  $ ((i > j)) && echo True
  $ ((i >= j)) && echo True
  $ ((i == j)) && echo True
  $ ((i != j)) && echo True
  True
  $ ((i < j)) && echo True
  True
  $ ((i <= j)) && echo True
  True
  $ ((i && j)) && echo True
  $ ((i || j)) && echo True
  True
  $ ((\! i)) && echo True
  True
  $ ((\! j)) && echo True
  $ ((i = j))
  $ echo $i
  1
  $ echo $j
  1
  ```

  This way of evaluating C-style expressions can be used in conjunction with `if`, `while` and `until` statements:

  ```bsh
  if((i == 0)); then
      # ...
  done
  ```

  ```bsh
  while((i == 0)); do
      # ...
  done
  ```

  ```bsh
  until((i == 0)); do
      # ...
  done
  ```

  Most notably, `(())` also allows to write C-style `for` loop conditions:

  ```bsh
  for((i = 0; i < 3; i++)); do
      # ...
  done
  ```
- C-style expressions evaluation doesn't support assigning the result of the evaluation; for that you can use arithmetic expansion (`$(())`), which allows for some sort of C-style expressions assignment:

  ```bsh
  $ i=0
  $ j=1
  $ k=$((i > j))
  $ echo $k
  0
  $ k=$((i < j))
  $ echo $k
  1
  $ x=$((1 + 2 + 3))
  $ echo $x
  6
  ```
- C-style prefixed / postfixed increment / decrement operators are also supported:

  ```bsh
  ++i
  i++
  --i
  i--
  ```

Comment: [Spaces in assignments in shell scripts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/258727/136107) says `var = 23` is not valid. Why is `while((i \!= 0)); do... done;` okay?

Comment: @tac Well that's not an assignment, it's a comparison (and by the way you don't need to escape `!`). However yeah, `((i=5))` would work. The culprit is with assignments of the type you mention (`x=foo`), because by surronunding the `=` with spaces (`x = foo`) that wouldn't be considered an assignment anymore, but rather a command `x` called with arguments `=` and `foo`. Does this clear that up?

Comment: This seems to be the way to go for me.  Are there any limitations within bash using this method in comparison to using standard bash syntax?

Comment: @RedDogAlpha `(( ))` is strictly for arithmetic - everything is treated as an integer.

Comment: @muru Well that's a big limitation!

Comment: @RedDogAlpha What muru said is what is occuring to me right now. Surprisingly you also have e.g. bitwise operators if you need them. However to be honest if you really need stuff like that you're probably better off just dropping any shell and start using a real programming language.

Comment: @kos Your right about dropping a shell, I just wanted to look at the options available to me. I also want to pick up knowledge as I go with the Linux subsystem, which is why I am asking about a shell. As muru continues to make points, it seems that sticking with BASH might be the best way to go. However, to the point of my question, it seems that TCSH fits the bill.

Comment: @RedDogAlpha Indeed, I just wanted to point out that Bash is not too far from C as far as syntax goes.